# Goroutine channel send data until wait group finishes

Tags: go, goroutine

I have module that has a long running go routine in it that doesn't complete until the end of the program.

I have a for loop that spawns other routines that feed into the channel.

The code is bulky so here is an example  that does basically the same thing.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    channel := someFunc()
    //unrelated routine
    go func() {
        time.Sleep(1000 * time.Hour)

    }()
    for resp := range channel {
        fmt.Println(resp)
    }

}

func someFunc() chan int {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    t := make(chan int, 10)
    arr := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}
    for _, i := range arr {
        wg.Add(1)

        go func(i int) {
            defer wg.Done()
            time.Sleep(time.Duration(i) * time.Second)

            t <- i

        }(i)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    close(t)
    return t
}
```

Removing the wait groups and `close()` (not having this causes the program to run forever) causes the program to run forever, but having them blocks the channel until all routines finish. How can I send data to the channel without making the program run indefinitely?

PS: the long running routine is in an imported module I do not have control over.

Comment: This program runs sequentially, not concurrently.`someFunc` will only return when everything is written to the channel, and all goroutines created by it are terminated. Then the main goroutine will read those, and then it will get the close indicator and terminate. I doubt this example illustrates the actual code that runs.

Comment: The routines in someFunc are concurrent, but the channel isn't returned until all routines finish. The for loop iterates through all results at once. I want to run it so I don't need a wait group to close the channel, but the channel must close after all routines in someFunc are terminated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is by adding another go routine. This allows the program to asynchronously wait to close the program.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    channel := someFunc()
    //unrelated routine
    go func() {
        time.Sleep(1000 * time.Hour)

    }()
    for resp := range channel {
        fmt.Println(resp)
    }

}

func someFunc() chan int {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    t := make(chan int, 10)
    arr := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}
    for _, i := range arr {
        wg.Add(1)

        go func(i int) {
            defer wg.Done()
            time.Sleep(time.Duration(i) * time.Second)

            t <- i

        }(i)
    }
    go func() {
        defer close(t)

        wg.Wait()

    }()
    return t
}
```